# "Doido de Pedra"? Por que "Pedra"; Qual o sentido?

Tags: significado, etimologia, expressões

Estava pensando sobre as expressões *doido varrido* e *doido de pedra*, que utilizamos do dia a dia sem perceber a sua razão de ser. Perguntei [aqui sobre *doido varrido*.](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3459/doido-varrido-por-que-varrido-qual-o-sentido)

Quanto à outra, por que dizemos que uma pessoa é “doida de pedra”?

Qual o sentido disso? Por que comparamos a loucura de alguém com uma pedra?

Pensando sobre, imaginei alguns significados:

- Será que se utiliza a pedra pelo fato de ser um objeto inanimado que não possui pensamento?
- Será que utilizam pedra por ser dura, querendo comprar com uma pessoa cabeça dura?

Sinceramente não sei o porque dessa expressão;

Comment: Hoje em dia a expressão "doido de pedra" tb pode conotar "usuário de crack"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Antigamente *"acreditava-se que os loucos eram aqueles que tinham uma pedra na cabeça."*. Isso foi [documentado](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Extra%C3%A7%C3%A3o_da_Pedra_da_Loucura) na Idade Média, entre 1475 e 1480, por um pintor Holandês, o Hieronymus Bosch.

[image: Uma espécie de operação cirúrgica durante a Idade Média, onde o cirurgião remove pedras da cabeça do homem louco que está sendo operado.]

Não só ele, mas outros também se preocuparam em *mostrar/satirizar* o procedimento de *trepanação* que era realizado nessa época para retirar pedras da cabeça dos indivíduos. Acreditava-se que elas deveriam ser removidas antes de contaminarem o cérebro totalmente, pois seriam causadoras de perturbações e problemas mentais.

Então, talvez esse seja o possível significado mais antigo para a expressão *"Doido de Pedra"*.

Comment: Sabe se isto está de alguma forma relacionado com o desenvolvimento da lobotomia?

Answer (score 5):

A expressão original é ***doido de pedras*** ou ***louco de pedras***, e os dicionários do século XIX explicam-na como “aquele que atira pedras”. O dicionário mais antigo em que encontrei a expressão é o de [António Moraes da Silva de 1831, no verbete *pedra*:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=20ZDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA436&lpg=PA436&dq=%22doido%20de%20pedras%20o%20que%20atira%20pedradas%22&source=bl&ots=v4VuLkSbk6&sig=y03AeAfgS20DZ7TXAhMAX2ZNuTo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO16Lcvo7OAhWBOBoKHXeXDnoQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22doido%20de%20pedras%20o%20que%20atira%20pedradas%22&f=false)

> PEDRA […] §. Doido de *pedras*, o que atira pedradas.

O [*Diccionario Encyclopedico* de José Maria de Almeida e Araujo Corrêa de Lacerda (4ª edição, Lisboa, 1874) no verbete *pedra*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=boJHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA747&dq=%22Doido%20de%20%E2%80%94s,%20que%20atira%20pedras%20desatinadamente:%20(fig.)%20homem%20estouvado%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj16obcv47OAhVIahoKHdJoAwUQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Doido%20de%20%E2%80%94s%2C%20que%20atira%20pedras%20desatinadamente%3A%20(fig.)%20homem%20estouvado%22&f=false) elabora um pouco mais:

> *Doido de —s*, que atira pedras desatinadamente: (fig.) homem estouvado.

Aparentemente, atirar pedras era uma coisa que os doidos faziam, pois Raphael Bluteau regista em 1713 o adágio «De *doudo* pedrada, ou má palavra» no seu [*Vocabulario Portuguez e Latino* (verbete *Doudo*):](http://purl.pt/13969/4/l-2773-a/l-2773-a_item4/l-2773-a_PDF/l-2773-a_PDF_24-C-R0090/l-2773-a_0000_capa-capa_t24-C-R0090.pdf)
[image]

As ocorrências mais antigas que encontrei da expressão no Google Books (século XVII, enquanto que com *pedra*, no singular, só em 1969) estão associadas ao arremesso de pedras, referindo-se ao episódio em que os judeus no templo tentaram apedrejar Jesus (João 8: 59). Na primeira [Frey Pedro Correa (*Triumphos Ecclesiasticos*, 1617)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=m3tYHay6iuAC&pg=RA5-PT129&dq=%22douda%20de%20pedras%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMirSfl4zOAhUG5xoKHUz-BX4Q6AEIPzAC#v=onepage&q=%22douda%20de%20pedras%22&f=false) diz que quem tomou pedras contra Jesus é como «douda de pedras» (foram homens que o fizeram, e as mulheres é que pagam; negrito meu em todas as citações):

> Mal pode levar caminho direito quӗ [quem] torce a Ley de Deos, & quando o Povo perdeo o entendimento offendendo a este Senhor , logo fez vontade de seus achaques descompondose tanto que como **douda de pedras** as toma contra o Filho de Deos , *tulerunt lapides ut jacerent in eum*;

Na segunda, o [Padre António Vieira (1608-97)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%B3nio_Vieira), distingue entre doidos que precisam de ir para o hospital psiquiátrico e os «doudos de pedra» que são os jusdeus que vinham preparados para apedrejar [(*Vieira Abbreviado em Cem Discursos Moraes, e Politicos*, 1746)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=yCa47wjlGSwC&pg=PA270&dq=%22doudos%20de%20pedras%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSxrK8kYzOAhWDBBoKHZMeDo4Q6AEINzAA#v=onepage&q=%22doudos%20de%20pedras%22&f=false)

> E quanto ao juizo , e ao uso da razaõ : *Quare*, diz o texo que tomaraõ pedras para atirarem a Christo : *Tulerunt ergo lapides , ut jacerent in eum.* No sagrado do templo nem as pedras eraõ taõ miúdas , nem taõ soltas , que as podessem tomar alli : final he logo , que já as traziaõ comsigo. Vede se mereciaõ ser levados á [casa dos Orates](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/casa-de-orates) [hospital psiquiátrico], pois naõ eraõ doudos , se não **doudos de pedras**.

[Fr. Jeronymo de Belem em *Chronica Serafica da Santa Provincia dos Algarves* (1753)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=W2FPAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA537&dq=%22louco%20de%20pedras%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiezeXtm4zOAhWBMBoKHderBjUQ6AEIdjAN#v=onepage&q=%22louco%20de%20pedras%22&f=false) também parece dizer que um louco de pedras é quem atira pedras:

> Nada disto passava por alto ao demónio; pois mal satisfeito da grande guerra , que a serva de Deos lhe fazia , procurou por todos os modos o persegui-la , e maltrata-la. Como **louco, de pedras** lhe atirava pedradas á janella da casa , em que dormia

Encontra-se na net sem grande fundamentação a tese, reproduzida nas outras respostas, de que a expressão se refere à chamada “pedra da loucura”. Passei em revista todos os exemplos de *doudo/doido/louco de pedras* do Google Books, incluindo variantes feminina e plural, e em nenhum caso encontrei nada que sugerisse a “pedra da loucura”. Também não encontrei no Google Books qualquer ocorrência de *pedra da loucura* anterior ao século XX; encontrei algumas *pedra da cabeça*, mas lendo o contexto, conclui-se que nada têm que ver com loucura. Não encontrei portanto qualquer indício que a crença da “pedra da loucura” tivesse existido em Portugal ou no Brasil.

No Google Books, *doido/louco de pedras* começa a rarear no século XIX, primeiro em Portugal, mais lá para o fim no Brasil. Depois, a partir de 1969, aparece em força no Brasil *doido de pedra*, juntamente com alguns *louco de pedras*.

Answer (score 4):

Sempre pensei que loucos de 'pedra' são aquele que, de tão louco que são, **atiram pedras**. Encontrei uma referência para esse entendimento [neste artigo](https://web.archive.org/web/20161117054050/http://fluxodopensamento.com/2012/04/louco-de-pedra/) de um blog sobre cultura e psiquiatria:

> [image: um desenho de um cirurgião operando um homem, passando uma lâmina atrás da orelha]
> Há quem acredite que a expressão "louco de pedra" não seja uma redução da frase "louco de atirar pedra", usada para denominar o indivíduo agressivo por conta da ausência do juízo da realidade.

No entanto, a figura que aparece neste site representa um cirurgião itinerante do século XVI extraindo pedras da cabeça de um homem:

> As pedras simbolizam a loucura e nesse tipo de procedimento após o corte do couro cabeludo, num movimento de prestidigitação, as pedras surgiam na mão do cirurgião. A seguir eram mostradas aos pacientes e atiradas fora, no intuito de curar o doente por sugestão.

[Na Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Extra%C3%A7%C3%A3o_da_Pedra_da_Loucura) também se fala sobre "A Extração da Pedra da Loucura", dizendo que antigamente se acreditava que os loucos eram aqueles que tinham uma pedra na cabeça.

Já no [Dicionário Informal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/doido+de+pedra/),  a palavra 'pedra' vem do nome calão para os comprimidos que os loucos tomavam no tratamento:

> Porque antigamente, os lôucos nos manicômios, eram submetidos à tratamentos com muita, excessiva mesmo, medicação em comprimidos.
>
> Daí, veio o apelido 'pedra', de comprimido.

Podemos perceber que existem vários sentidos para esta expressão, mas acredito que a resposta mais plausível, sobre a origem de louco de 'pedra', esteja nas crenças da idade média sobre a existência de uma 'pedra' na cabeça.

Answer (score -6):

Não há expressão mais contemporânea, que transite tao livremente no tempo, pois ainda que não se tenha certeza de sua real origem ou significado. Podemos certamente afirmar que hoje trata-se do uso de drogas, aludida a pedra maldita a pedra de craque ou crack; Que causa as mais inusitadas atitudes por parte dos seus usuários, e os compara e equipara ao loucos doentes mentais de outrora.

Comment: Etimologia popular, manifestamente falsa, já que há exemplos muito mais antigos do uso da expressão.

Comment: Muita gente fala primeiro e pensa depois, assim muitos pensam que é de craque, assumindo. Então, o que dizes é tão confiável quanto o que diz alguém maluco de pedra. Por isto, las referências!