# “Doido varrido”? Por que “varrido”? Qual o sentido?

Tags: significado, etimologia, expressões

Perguntei [aqui qual a razão da expressão *doido de pedra*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/doido-de-pedra-por-que-pedra-qual-o-sentido). Do mesmo modo, por que dizemos que uma pessoa é ***doida varrida***?

Qual o sentido disso? Por que dizemos que ela está *varrida*? De onde vem a vassoura?

Tentei imaginar o porquê, e não me veio nada que encaixe. Alguém que era doido e gostava de varrer?

Sinceramente não sei o porquê dessa expressão.

Comment: Fleurquer, com respostas e edições, as duas perguntas vão provavelmente acabar longe uma da outra. Incluí links nas duas, para uma pessoa que veja uma poder encontrar a outra. Sobre *porque, por que, porquê* e *por quê*, vê [esta pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1/como-usar-corretamente-por-que-por-qu%C3%AA-porque-ou-porqu%C3%AA)

Comment: @Jacinto obrigado, ainda não sei muito bem usar as coisas aqui.

Comment: Se clicares em "edited não sei quantos mins ago", abaixo da tua pergunta, podes ver como é que eu fiz o link. A maneira mais prática é copiares o endereço (com Ctrl+C), e na edição da pergunta clicas no terceiro símbolo a contar da esquerda acima da caixa de edição (ou fazendo Ctrl+L) e colas o endereço na caixa que aparece.

Comment: Doido varrido pode ter a ver com os mendigos sendo varridos das portas das casas

Answer (score 16, accepted):

***Varrido*** neste contexto parece vir de ***varrido de juízo***: como se o juízo se tivesse varrido da cabeça, tal como se diz que se nos varreu algo da memória. Este é o entendimento do dicionarista Raphael Bluteau já há quase trezentos anos [(*Vocabulário Portuguez e Latino*, 1721):](http://purl.pt/13969/3/l-2778-a/l-2778-a_item3/index.html#/388)

> VARRIDO. Limpo com vassoura […]
>   Doudo varrido. Totalmente doudo, como se disseramos , que se lhe varreo todo o entendimento de sorte , que não tem horas boas, nem lucidos intervallos.

***Varrido do juízo*** é precisamente a expressão mais antiga em que eu consegui encontrar *varrido* associado a loucura. Aparece em 1593-95, em *Primeira visitação do Santo Officio ás partes do Brasil, pelo licenciado Heitor Furtado de Mendoça: Denunciações de Pernambuco, 1593-95*; o OCR do Google não é infalível — creio que a frase é «varrido do juízo falando desvarios» (ênfase minha em todas as citações):
[image]

Se a ocorrência mais antiga de *varrido do juízo* vem da Inquisição, a segunda mais antiga é da Maçonaria, no [Manifesto do IR. Lycurgo, Gr. Insp. Ger. da Ordem dos Franc-Maçons em Portugal, 1849:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=u6FkAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA152&dq=%22varrido%20do%20ju%C3%ADzo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5oJqgoYfOAhUB2B4KHW35Ag0Q6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22varrido%20do%20ju%C3%ADzo%22&f=false)

> Comtudo um homem , levantado do pó a empregado subalterno de justiça, apparecia agora, **varrido do juízo**, a querer zombar de quantos tinham assento na Gr. L.

Parece-me portanto que a expressão *doido varrido* surgiu por simples justaposição: *varrido do juízo*, significando ‘sem juízo’, foi justaposto a *doido* para reforço da ideia, perdendo-se depois o *do juízo*. Ou então perdeu-se primeiro *do juízo* e justapôs-se *varrido* a doido, pois também se encontra simplesmente *varrido* com o significado de louco. A ocorrência mais antiga que encontrei é de 1755 em [Francisco de Pina e de Mello, *A Buccolica*:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=aaZgAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> Onde estás louco onde estás?
>   que depois que andas **varrido**
>   trazes o gado perdido?
>
> Deixaste fato, e cabana
>   o montado, e a companhia,
>   isto por huma serrana,
>   que já to naõ merecia
>
> […]
>
> Se tu vaqueiro naõ cuidas
>   Que tudo nella he fingido,
>   digo entaõ que andas **varrido.**

Outros exemplos:

> O homem **vai varrido**! Ora queira Deus! Queira Deus que ele não vá para aí fazer alguma! Nossa Senhora nos livre de tentações do Demónio e dos maus inimigos da alma. [[Júlio Dinis, *Uma Família Inglesa*, 1870]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=m98FAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA302&dq=%22O%20homem%20vai%20varrido%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTvKvAxIfOAhXIxRQKHYwkCgwQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22O%20homem%20vai%20varrido%22&f=false)
>
> É que a pequena, depois de pedir muito à avó que se compadecesse dela e obtivesse do pai liberdade para se casar com o cabra, abriu a chorar e a lamentar-se como **uma varrida**! [[Aluísio Azevedo, *O Mulato*, 1909]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=LXxcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT383&dq=%22lamentar-se%20como%20uma%20varrida%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8mtaBxYfOAhWGNxQKHRNzDzcQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=%22lamentar-se%20como%20uma%20varrida%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Os pacientes varriam as escadarias do Hospital.

Exemplo: Sujeito é Doido varrido mesmo.

Falso amigo: Louco de Pedra.
Vem, pelo contrário, de comprimido (pedra).

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas — por exemplo com referências. Você tem alguma para tuas afirmações?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).